# Why does nuget command work in Debug, but not Release?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

I'm trying to exec a nuget command BeforeBuild that is different in Debug then when its Release.

My .csproj has this in it:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <Exec Command="Update-Package PackageName -IncludePrerelease"></Exec>
</Target>

<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="Update-Package PackageName -Safe"></Exec>
</Target>
```

The top one (Debug) works as intended.  The bottom one (Release) throws an error:

> 'The command "Update-Package PackageName -Safe" exited with code 9009'
>   // 'Update-Package' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command

A little research shows me that is basically saying it can't exec the command because its ignorant of it, but why is Debug working then?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, don't really know, but you are passing different parameters. Debug has `-IncludePrerelease` while Release has `-Safe`. Also, if this is a custom command, maybe the release path is not in the environment?

Comment: It seems like the issue is the command, not the arguments. You should try making the commands the same to see if you still have the problem, reducing the number of ways it could've failed. (Getting closer to a [MCVE]!) It does seem like this isn't enough information so far.

Comment: Thanks for the responses :).  It feels like nuget.exe is only installed in Debug and not Release.  For the time being, I'll probably just work around it with how I pack the nuget package via TeamCity